# How can I refresh a data source from an R package automatically? Specifically the coronavirus CRAN package data

Tags: r, automation, refresh

I am working with the Johns Hopkins coronavirus R package, but I haven't yet figured out how to get it to provide me with the underlying updated data each day. I have restarted R and reloaded the package, but it seems as though the data is static from when I installed the package. It does not provide updated data each time I run it unless I reinstall the package. The data behind this package gets updated nightly on the repository. I'm trying to figure out a good way to have mine updated daily as well.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

````
library(coronavirus) 
library(dplyr)

data("coronavirus")

summary_df <- coronavirus %>% group_by(Country.Region, type) %>%
  summarise(total_cases = sum(cases)) %>%
  arrange(-total_cases)
df <- coronavirus %>%
  group_by(Province.State,Country.Region,Lat,Long,type) %>%
  mutate(TotalCasesRegion = cumsum(cases))```
````

Comment: There are no methods (that I can see) in this package to refresh the data. Reinstalling the package is the only way to get the latest data.

Comment: Creating a scheduled task on your computer (or some other computer) can vary across operating systems. Which OS are you using? I can demo a short batch script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to grab the dataset from the package author's project on GitHub (assuming this data makes its way into the package as-is).

```
download.file("https://github.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus/raw/master/data/coronavirus.rda", "cv")
load("cv")
```

Seems to be the latest dataset:

```
max(coronavirus$date)
[1] "2020-03-04"

nrow(coronavirus)
[1] 2777
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you!